# do "for loop" for table division and frequency word calculation

Tags: r, for-loop, corpus

I would need to divide this dataframe of 1038319 rows into smaller tables of 25k each, then on each table I have to do the following operation, at the beginning I was doing manually table by table, such as the first two in the following code

```
comments1 <- comments[1:25000,]

texts1 = comments1$message

corpus1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts1))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, toSpace, "-")
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, toSpace, "http")
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, toSpace, ":")
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removeNumbers)
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removePunctuation)
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, stripWhitespace)

dtm1 = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus1)
freq1 <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm1))
ord1 <- order(freq1, decreasing = TRUE)
freq1[head(ord1)]

wf1 = data.frame(word = names(freq1), 
                 freq = freq1)

#-----------------


comments2 <- comments[25001:50000,]

texts2 = comments2$message

corpus2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts2))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, toSpace, "-")
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, toSpace, "http")
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, toSpace, ":")
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, removeNumbers)
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, removePunctuation)
corpus2 <- tm_map(corpus2, stripWhitespace)

dtm2 = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus2)
freq2 <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm2))
ord2 <- order(freq2, decreasing = TRUE)
freq2[head(ord2)]

wf2 = data.frame(word = names(freq2), # 
                 freq = freq2)
```

this above and the example code part of the operation I should do, here I do it for the first two tables, the ranges are 25k of rows, Is there a way to do "for loop"?

Then I would also like to sum all the resulting WF tables into one.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, i.e., some data to work with (even just a small subsample, or simulated data resembling the original ones), and a small working code with all the packages needed to run it?

Comment: the code i posted works, how can i post dataset?

Comment: You  may post the output of `dput()` applied to few rows of your data (say 100).

Comment: since there is some text it comes out incomprehensible

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is define a function to process the text and then pass each grouping of comments to that functions for processing.

See comments below for the step by step instructions:

```
#define the function
processtext <- function(comment) {
   texts = comments1$message
   corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))

   toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "-")
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "http")
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, ":")
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
   corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

   dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
   freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
   ord <- order(freq, decreasing = TRUE)

   wf = data.frame(word = names(freq), freq = freq)
}

#number of lines per groups
n<- 100
#determine the number groups
numberofgroups <- length(comments$message) %/%n +1
#split into a list of groups
listofcomments <- split(comments, rep(1:numberofgroups, each=n))

#process the list groups
#returns a list of answers
answer <- lapply(listofcomments, processtext)
```

Now all of the results for each group is stored in one list, which can be further process as a list or individually with `answer[[1]]`